# How do I make many-to-many field optional in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many

When you have a many-to-many relationship (`related_name`, not `through`) and you are trying to use the admin interface you are required to enter one of the relationships even though it does not have to exist for you to create the first entry.

I'm creating an app that is an event organizer. Imagine we had `Event` and `Group` models, bound with many-to-many relationship.

Django [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) creates another table with the indices of the two other tables.
**But I see no reason why this extra table *has* to be populated.**

If I work with the database through phpMyAdmin I can create a `Group` without registering an `Event`, since the connection between the two is only through a separate table, and there is no database value enforcement at given level.

How do I make the admin interface this realize it?
**How do I make the many-to-many field optional in Django?**

Answer (score 509, accepted):

If you want to be able to specify ManyToMany relation without making it required just use `blank=True`:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    ...
    events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank=True)
```

Comment: This does solve the problem. Using the blank was not as obvious to me because I thought the manytomany created a table that links the events with the groups (events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, related_name="groups", blank=True) So it was not clear to use the blank since Event is not actually a field in the group table. Anyway it worked so thank you!!!

Comment: You mean you have to use both `blank=True` and `null=True`?

Comment: @omouse I think yes, blank is for django validation, and null for the database. In this kind of case (like for IntegerField) it makes no sense to put one without the other I think

Comment: Do you really need to have `null=True`? I was under the impression `null` doesn't have any affect on `ManyToMany` fields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243039/south-migrating-foriegn-key-many-to-many-field-to-null-true-blank-true-doesnt

Comment: Yeah, um @TylerHayes is right. null=True is basically a no-op and is nonsensical in the context of a ManyToMany. I'm open to being shown how I'm mistaken.

Comment: null=True is not required, at least from Django 1.5 onwards.

Comment: I use the "through" and get the error with "blank=true", when I had created a many to many entry and then do not need it any more (remove from dropdown). I then get "field required" after saving.

Comment: Is this working both ways ? For instance, do you have something to do in the Event model as well, so that Events can be created without having to specify a Group list ?

Comment: @Overdrivr Of course. That would be true even if there wasn't `blank = True` here.

Comment: From django documentation
null has no effect since there is no way to require a relationship at the database level.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomany-arguments

Comment: it courious if I set `blank=True, null=True` the Warning remains if I delete null=True it dissapears/

Answer (score 3):

If Ludwik's answer does not solve the issue, set required to false in the serializer as well:

```
class RecipeDetailSerializer(RecipeSerializer):
    """Recipe detail serializer"""
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```