# Can a model have a list of ForeignKey objects?

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to create a relationship between Shops and Categories where a shop might have multiple categories and was thinking how possible it is to create a list of Category objects in a variable inside the Shop object. Or what is the better approach?

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

class Shop(models.Model):
    categories = list(models.ForeignKey(Category,...))
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be referring to **ManyToManyField** relationship.

Might be related to:
[How do I make many-to-many field optional in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529472/how-do-i-make-many-to-many-field-optional-in-django)

Django docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/